# interacting with a user created gui dynamically using python

Tags: python

There is a user created GUI which is an .exe that loads a DLL. This GUI has a bunch of sliders, check boxes etc. I would like to move two sliders at the same time using python automatically without me using my mouse to move the sliders. I would like to know the python modules that an be used to achieve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SikuliX](http://sikulix.com/).

It can be used to automate mouse or keyboard actions based on pattern matching. It is originally developed for Java I think, but it [can be used with Python](https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios.html#using-jython-and-python).

Basically, anything you can do yourself manually can be done with it.

The developer seems to be pretty active, so you can easily seek help from him if you have issues.